# Non italic math mode symbols?

Tags: math-mode, units

I would like to insert a `\mu` command to form `$\mu$` m (micro meters)
i.e. as a unit, not a variable.

This means I do not want `\mu` to be italic. However, LaTeX only accepts the
`\mu` command in math-mode and therefore it appears in italic....

`\mathrm{\mu}` does not work.

Any ideas on how can to change this into a regular upright symbol?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: To typeset any units with LaTeX, you should use the package `siunitx`. You will find lots of examples here at TeX.SX.

Comment: this is covered by the question [Best way to typeset micrometers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522/579)

Comment: This answer may also help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Answer (score 43):

It is better to use `siunitx` for units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\SI{100}{\micro\meter}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Without the great `siunitx` package, in this case you can also:

1) If you use `xetex` or `luatex` compilers, insert `\usepackage{fontspec}` in the preamble and simply write `µ` (`altGr`+`m` in Linux, `Alt`+`230` in Windows).

2) If you use the `pdflatex` compiler:

- Write `\textmu{}` if you load the `textcomp` package in the preample.
- Write  `µ` as above if you load both `textcomp` and `inputenc` with the `uft8` option (but do not use `fontspec` with `pdflatex`). If you have some problem here, check that the file itself have really a UTF8 encoding. Add also some beautiful font, since the default *mu* is ugly.

Aside, note that text in math mode is not necessarily italic nor slanted text, depending of the font. A MWE with `pdflatex` showing the four *mu* styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % for textex or luatex
\usepackage{palatino} % font to avoid the ugly default µ
\begin {document}
\obeylines
Four styles of \textmu:
100 µm    
100 \textsl{µ}m
100 \textit{µ}m
100 $\mu$m
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

3) Some fine `\textmu` variants are also provided by the `textgreek` package through the options `cbgreek` (default), `euler` and `artemisia` but note that the `textcomp` command have precedence. Fortunately, `textgreek` provide the alternative `\textmugreek` 
command in case you are using both packages. To avoid typing the command, you can make that  `µ` character print `\textmugreek` instead `\textmu` adding this to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{µ}{\textmugreek}
```

4) Using `babel` with `greek` option you can also use `\greektext m \latintext` to obtain µ. You can also simplify this coding as above or by a simple macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace
\newcommand{\micron}{\greektext m\latintext m\xspace}
\begin{document}
100 \micron
\end{document}
```

5) Use `upgreek` package and `$\upmu$`. This in a only math command but you can make your own  `\Mu` command compatible with both math and text mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,xspace}
\def\Mu{\ensuremath\upmu\xspace}
\begin{document}
Write \Mu in text or math mode because $\Mu\neq\mu$
\end{document}
```

6) The same as above but using `txfonts` package and `$\muup$`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `\textmu` (without `$$` symbols), for instance: `2 \textmu m` for 2 µm

Comment: This is included in the answer by Fran, which also explains which package you need to load.