# textmu in hepthesis class

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

I try to get hepthesis running but run into a problem when using `\textmu` Here a code example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{hepthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    $\mu$ , \textmu
\end{document}
```

which results into:

```
Error: Command \textmu unavailable in encoding OT1.
Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes'
Warning: No multilingual support.
```

I do now about `\textmugreek` but it looks different and quite pixely (might be a viewer problem...)

Is there a way to make `\textmu` work?

Comment: `\usepackage{textcomp}`

Comment: @Johannes_B. Works like a charm thank you. You might want to upgrade it to an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144569/non-italic-math-mode-symbols

Comment: @Johannes_B & Andrew Swann. I don't think so. Since I'm not able to print a symbol. It's not that I don't know its name

Comment: @magu_ But that question encompasses yours. Look through the answers - it isn't just about identifying the symbol but also producing it. You just don't need stage 1 of that process. Stage 2 is no different whether you first need to learn the name or already know it ;).