# How do I get the proper microsymbol, μ not mu, not \textmu because that looks ugly, but the clean one?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How do I get a clean looking \micro symbol  µ ?

[image]

I want a micro symbol, not a greek \mu, because that is another symbol.
However tex does not render the proper symbol, and the symbol that is does render looks like it was stolen from a different font.
The 2nd variant is not much better.

How do I get a \micro symbol that actually looks like it was not copy-pasted from comic-sans?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
  \begin{scope}
  \path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (433.62,252.94);
  \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

  \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1] at (242.01, 10.00) 
{Time in μ $\text{\textmu{}} \text{seconds}$, $n = 125\,000$};
% the unicode char "μ" does not render. And it has better not look like #2 above >-:< 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) why don't you take a step back and look into the `siunitx` package. (3) using language like "looks like it was drawn by a 2-year old" does not really make others want to help you.

Comment: My alternative here, of slanting the italic Greeks into an upright posture, is another possibility you can reject: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Comment: and I thought my handwriting was bad.... ;-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I'd love to try it, but MikTex cannot find \usepackage{mathptmx} anywhere.

Comment: The unicode symbol in your question is `Unicode Character 'GREEK SMALL LETTER MU' (U+03BC)`, so it is quite unclear what you mean by not wanting a greek mu.

Comment: MikTeX uses the name psnfss instead of mathptmx.  It tends to group packages into bundles with new names.  The CTAN website provides the MikTeX name when different.

Comment: ? The first one is the "proper" symbol? It's okay if you don't like the glyph, but it is a µ symbol. Remember you're use a serif font. If you use a version without serifs in the midst of a serif font, that's not using the "proper" symbol

Comment: Not sure why you don't consider the second example as “the same font”. Of course the Latin alphabet doesn't contain a glyph for mu; the glyph in the second example is taken from the Greek version of the Computer Modern fonts.

Comment: @Au101, it the the \mu symbol, not the \micro symbol. The \micro symbol in computer science is a different symbol from the greek letter mu.

Comment: In the first line of your question you used a mu U+03BC μ  not micro U+00B5 µ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't like the micro symbol from `siunitx`, I try something else:

Use `unicode-math` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
10 $\symup{\mu}$s
\end{document}
```

## Edit:

As @Mico stated in the comments, you should combine `unicode-math` with `siunitx` by defining a new command – it is more natural IMHO:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx} 
\newcommand\upmicro{\symup{\mu}} 
\begin{document} 
\SI{10}{\upmicro\second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, although not technically very serif-ish, it does match the curvyness of CMU computer modern nicely. Much easier on the eyes.

Comment: +1. It's straightforward to combine this method with the `siunitx` package and its `\SI` macro. E.g., `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx} \newcommand\upmicro{\symup{\mu}} \begin{document} \SI{10}{\upmicro\second} \end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this rather drastic solution given in the answer by 
user11232 in [this StackExchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144569/non-italic-math-mode-symbols) quite satisfying (on GNU/Linux i.e. Fedora using pdflatex). I noticed that the mu character looked different there from that on my system when using siunitx package (without using the libertine package). The solution is drastic because it changes the font for the whole document but the libertine fonts are beautiful. In summary the solution comes down to using a combination of the siunitx and the libertine package. Example screenshots with and without libertine package are included below

```
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Examples

without libertine:[image]

with libertine:[image]

Comment: I've specified the source by mentioning the user that posted the answer I am referring to. Additionally I have explained how it led me to the solution I've posted here.