# Why aren't\textrm{} and \text{} working in math mode ($$) with PdfLatex

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, text

When trying to write a mathematical symbol using the regular font (i.e not italics) in math-mode as displayed in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt, a4paper, elec, utf8, a-1b]{mythesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
...equipped with a 50$\textrm{\mu}$m slit...
\end{document}
```

a error is produced saying:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                 $
l.684 ... equipped with a 50$\textrm{\mu}$m slit, and...
```

I am trying to compile the file using PdfLaTeX, and haven't found anything indicating that it shouldn't work. I have also tried deleting corrupted aux files and tried using `\text{}` instead of `\textrm{}` but the same error is produced. I have also tried using `\mathrm{}` but in my case the font remains the same as it would regularly be in math mode.

To reiterate, how can I write a mathematical symbol in a regular font when `\text`, `\textrm`, `\mathrm{}` are not working? Is there another method to write mathematical symbols in a regular font?

Thanks already in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Because you need to put `\mu` in math mode, not in `\textrm{}`.

Comment: \mu needs math mode, but with \textrm you are switching to text mode. This won't work. Use siunitx to typeset such things. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549/2388

Comment: There is `\mathrm` for math mode, but that does not work for `\mu` (it doesn't produce an error like `$\textrm{\mu}$` does, but the output is not what you expected). I agree with Ulrike that you are quite probably looking for `siunitx`: `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then `\SI{50}{\micro\metre}`.

Comment: Thank you @moewe, siunitx was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was explained by @marmot, `\textrm{}`, when used inside math mode exits the math mode environment thus making the syntax `$\textrm{\mu}$` wrong.

One possible solution as described by marmot is to use the `siunitx` package

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
...equipped with a \SI{50}{\micro\meter} slit...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test that code? It is usually written as `\SI{50}{\micro\meter}$

Comment: and the name of the package is siunitx.

Comment: Yup, I tested the code and it workd fine for me when compiling with pdfLaTeX.