# Re-define "mu" in "$\mu$m" for units (upright \mu instead of italic \mu)

Tags: math-mode, equations, math-operators, units

I have a 300+ page thesis and I constantly used `$\mu$`, which showcases mu in italic format. Now my supervisor wants me to correct this to non-italic. I do not want to change each one-by-one, therefore thought to re-define it by using: `\newcommand{\mu}{\ensuremath{\textrm{\mu}}}`

But ofc I cannot do it since `\mu` is already defined. How can I re-define it such that it is not in italic in my equation, without changing all one-by-one? Certain things in math format$$ should remain italic though..

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
   
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
    
\begin{document}
5 $\mu$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should all lower case Greek letters be upright? Or are you using the `\mu`s as units, such as in 5 micro metres?

Comment: I am using it as units!

Comment: your error is not so much that mu is already defined but that you are defining it in terms of itself (so it will be an infinite loop) you could fix that but I woulduse a different name such as `\textmu`  or `\micro` and globally change your `\mu` to `\micro` first which should only be a few seconds in any text editor

Answer (score 29):

Per your comments, you are using "mu" to denote "micro", as in *one millionth* of some scientific unit. Given this situation, you need to get out of the business of attempting to define your own micro symbol immediately. Instead, do please employ the `siunitx` package and its `\unit` and `\qty` macros to typeset scientific units and associated quantities. The macros `\unit` and `\qty` can be used in both text and math mode.

[image]

Observe that the typographically correct glyph for "micro" has serifs and is quite different from both `$\mu$` and `$\upmu$`. Do also observe that `\qty` also automatically inserts a typographically correct amount of (non-breakable) whitespace between the number and associated unit.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,upgreek}

\begin{document}
\unit{\micro\meter}, $\unit{\micro\farad}$, \unit{\micro\second}

$\qty{4}{\micro\meter}$, \qty{5}{\micro\farad}, $\qty{6}{\micro\second}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `siunitx` package provides the shortcut macros `\ug`, `\um`, `\us`, `\umol`, `\uA`, `\uV`, and `\uL` to denote one millionth gram, meter/metre, second, mol, Ampere, Volt, and Liter, respectively. Thus, the first line in the body of the `document` environment above could also be written succinctly as `\unit{\um}, $\unit{\uF}$, \unit{\us}`.

Answer (score 11):

I guess it's too late to have correct input. You can solve your problem by using `upgreek` and redefining `\mu` to be `\upmu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}

\begin{document}

$\mu$ but $\pi\alpha\beta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In general, italic greeks do not present upright via `\mathrm` or `\textrm`.  Here, I recommend the answer [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220) which, for pdflatex, allows unslanting of any glyph.

Then, I save the italic mu as `\itmu` and redefine `\mu` in terms of it.  One can still call upon `\itmu` if the italic mu is required.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\let\itmu\mu
\renewcommand\mu{\ensuremath{\unslant\itmu}}

\begin{document}
5 \mu m.  If needed italic in math mode, $\alpha\itmu$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of the options [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522/best-way-to-typeset-micrometers).  You probably want either the `siunitx` package or `\textmicrometer` from the laTeX kernel.  If you could redefine `\mu`, you could also do a search-and-replace.

The problem you’re getting with `\newcommand` can be fixed very simply, however, by using `\DeclareRobustCommand`.  With some packages that delay their definitions for various reasons, you might need `\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareRobustCommand\mu{\textup{\textmicrometer}}}`.